# enableClientBasedCulture vs culture in web.config

Tags: asp.net, culture

What is the difference between these two settings:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto"/>
```

vs

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="auto"/>
```

Does culture="auto" override enableClientBasedCulture="false" in the second case?

Answer (score 4):

msdn says `enableClientBasedCulture` is not used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100).aspx